# How can I switch language dynamically in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I want to switch language between English and Chinese, so I create two language files:

messages_en.properties
messages_zh.properties

and in jsp file, my code as below:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${language=='en'}">
    <a href='<c:url value="/language?language=zh" />'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk'></i>&nbsp;
        <s:message code="label.language" />
    </a>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <a href='<c:url value="/language?language=en" />'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk'></i>&nbsp;
        <s:message code="label.language" />
    </a>
</c:otherwise>
```

and in controller file, my code as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/language" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String switchLanguage(@RequestParam("language") String language,
        ModelMap model) {
    Locale currentLocale = null;

    if ("zh".equals(language)) {
        currentLocale = new Locale("zh", "CN");
    } else if ("en".equals(language)) {
        currentLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
    }
    model.put("language", currentLocale.getLanguage());

    return "/book/index";
}
```

and in .xml file, i config MessageSource as below:

```
 <bean id="messageSource" 
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:language/messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

How can I change my controller action code to switch language dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(language);
```

to get the right Locale. `language` can be something like "en" or "en_US". Problem is that you only get the language from your requestParameter and you know by definition which country to use.

I'd create a map for this containing the languages as Keys and the countries as values. Thus you can do

```
String languageCountry = language + "_" + myCountryMap.get(language); // returns "US"
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(languageCountry );
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor` bean.

It looks like that is what you are missing, or trying to write yourself.  It picks up the `?language=en` URL parameter and changes this user's session locale for you.

[A good tutorial here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/)

Comment: The tutorial uses ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping which is deprecated in Spring 4.3.4